# how to get comma separated values in one column for multiple rows that have same id

Tags: sql, aginity

[image: before]
before

[image: after]
after

tried few functions but didnt work

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: im using aginity pro

Answer (score 0):

Some databases (like MySql or MariaDb) support a group_concat() function that can be used in conjunction with GROUP BY:

```
select
  id,
  group_concat(distinct value separator ',')
from table
group by id
```

Some other databases may have a similar function with a different name (STRING_AGG() for example), try to check your db documentation...